# Python Neural Network for XOR

Tags: python, neural-network

I have the following python code which implements a simple neural network (two inputs, one hidden layer with 2 neurons, and one output) with a sigmoid activation function to learn a XOR gate. The code runs fine (ie no syntax errors or runtime errors or anything) and I have it plotting error over time to visualize its progress.

I have tested it piece by piece; I know the feedforward works correctly as I tried hardcoding in weights and feeding it through and it gave the expected results, and while I didn't have the patience to backpropagate errors for the entire network by hand, I worked out the errors on the output and one of the hidden layer nodes and got similar numbers to the code. However, when I try to train it on the 4 test cases I have cyclically, the network consistently converges to `0.5`. I've tried changing various parameters (`learning rate`, `momentum`, `epochs`, etc.) but to no avail. I even tried replacing the `sigmoid` function with `tanh` for the activation but that didn't change the results either.

I've used `numpy` in some places to make the matrix/vector math cleaner. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how I can improve my code, as well as what could be causing my problem.

```
import numpy as np
from random import random
from math import tanh, exp
from copy import deepcopy
LAYERS = [2, 2, 1]
testCases = [
    [[0, 0], [0]],
    [[0, 1], [1]],
    [[1, 0], [1]],
    [[1, 1], [0]]
]

activate = np.vectorize(lambda c: 1 / (1 + exp(-c))) #activation function
_activate = np.vectorize(lambda c: activate(c) * (1 - activate(c))) #derivative of activation function




errors = [list(), list(), list(), list()]

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.topology = top
        self.layers = [np.matrix([0 for i in range(size)]).T for size in top]
        self.weights = list()
        for i,j in zip(top[:-1], top[1:]):
            self.weights.append(np.matrix([[random()*2-1 for _ in range(i + 1)] for _ in range(j)]))
        self.momentum = 0.3
        self.dw = None

    def feedforward(self, inputs):
        assert len(inputs) == self.topology[0]
        self.layers[0] = np.matrix(inputs[:]).T
        for i in range(len(self.layers) - 1):
            biased = np.concatenate((self.layers[i], np.matrix([1])), axis=0)
            self.layers[i + 1] = activate(self.weights[i] @ biased)

        return self.layers[-1]


    def backpropagate(self, test):
        inputs, expected = test
        self.feedforward(inputs) # load the inputs into the network
        deltas = deepcopy(self.layers)
        errors[testCases.index(test)].append(np.linalg.norm(expected - self.layers[-1]))
        deltas[-1] = np.dot(expected - self.layers[-1], _activate(self.layers[-1]))
        for i in range(len(deltas) - 1)[::-1]:

            try:
                sc = deltas[i+1].T @ self.weights[i]
            except ValueError:
                sc = deltas[i+1][:-1,:].T @ self.weights[i]
            biased = np.concatenate((self.layers[i], [[1]])) #layer with a bias node of 1 added to it
            deltas[i] = np.multiply(_activate(biased), sc.T)
        self.deltas = deltas[1:]

    def test(self, test):
        self.backpropagate(test)
        for i in range(len(self.deltas)):
            biased = np.concatenate((self.layers[i], [[1]])).T
            if self.deltas[i].shape[0] is not self.weights[i].shape[0]:
                self.deltas[i] = self.deltas[i][:-1, :]
            assert self.deltas[i].shape[0] == self.weights[i].shape[0]
            assert biased.shape[1] == self.weights[i].shape[1]

            dw = self.deltas[1] @ biased
            if self.dw is not None:
                dw += self.momentum * self.dw
            self.weights[i] += 0.1 * dw
            self.dw = dw


nn = NeuralNetwork(LAYERS)

print(nn.weights)
nn.test(testCases[0])
print(nn.deltas)
for i in range(1000):
    nn.test(testCases[i % 4])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
list(map(plt.plot, errors))
plt.show()


list(map(print, nn.feedforward([0, 0])))
list(map(print, nn.feedforward([0, 1])))
list(map(print, nn.feedforward([1, 0])))
list(map(print, nn.feedforward([1, 1])))
```

UPDATE: I took the time and backpropagated the errors by hand for a couple of random initial configurations, and my results matched what the network calculates. Also, I ran it once on each test case and saw that the error for that test case improved marginally after the update, so I know my backprop and weight update steps are correct. Unfortunately, it still converges on bad values. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you saying, it works but it doesn't?